# How do I solve file ignored in /etc/apt/sources.list and release file not found errors while updating APT cache?

Tags: apt, updates

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update` and running in these kinds of errors.

```
N: Ignoring file 'libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Well, `.deb` files simply don't belong in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory - move them somewhere else or remove them. The other issue has been addressed many times e.g. [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: @steeldriver What PPA should I purge in this case?

Comment: Purge the PPA listed on the E: line.

Comment: @user535733 How do I get the name? can you paste the command?

Comment: It's right there in your output.

Answer (score 3):

You can go and remove these deb files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.
Open your terminal and run this command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.deb
```